# How to use dynamic programming to split string into words? (Python, recursion, memoization)

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to write a piece of dynamic programming code that allows me to split a string into valid words (validity is determined by dictionary lookup).

If the string cannot be split into valid words, I want to return ''.

#

Here's the first version of my code:

```
dictionary = {'cat':1,'hat':1,'in':1}

def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    def memoize_function(*args):
        if args[0] not in cache:
            cache[args[0]] = f(*args)  # compute and cache result
        return cache[args[0]]
        memoize_function.cache = cache  
    return memoize_function

@memoize
def splitintowords_version1(mystring, word_list):
    if len(mystring) < 1:
        return word_list
    else:
        for i in range(len(mystring)):
            current_word = mystring[:i+1]
            remaining_word = mystring[i+1:]
            if current_word in dictionary:
                word_list = word_list + current_word + ' ' 
                return splitintowords_version1(remaining_word, word_list)
            if i == len(mystring)-1 and current_word not in dictionary:
                word_list = ''
                return word_list
```

While strictly speaking, the code works, I know it's not using dynamic programming properly, because the full list of words is being passed even though the string is getting shorter.  For example, after calling splitintowords_version1('catinhat'), splitintowords_version1.cache contains the following nonsense:

{'':'cat in hat'}

#

I then rewrote the program:

```
@memoize                
def splitintowords_version2(mystring):
    if len(mystring) < 1:
        return ''
    else:
        for i in range(len(mystring)):
            current_word = mystring[:i+1]
            remaining_word = mystring[i+1:]
            if current_word in dictionary:
                return current_word + ' ' + splitintowords_version2(remaining_word)
            if i == len(mystring)-1 and current_word not in dictionary:
                return ''
```

This version caches values appropriately, but it returns an incorrect value for splitintowords_version2('catinhata').  It returns 'cat in hat ', instead of ''.

I feel like I'm missing just one last piece to get the code right.  Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, this is NOT homework.

Comment: Your `memoize()` function only appears to key off of the first argument.  This means if you use it to wrap a function taking multiple arguments, it will incorrectly return a cached return value based on the first argument only, even if the second argument differs.

Comment: But I want cache to key off of the string, rather than the list of words. The hope is cache will read something like this: {'cathat':'cat hat', 'inhat':'in hat'}

Comment: That may be fine for this function, just letting you know that you can't apply it to any random function and expect it to work.

Comment: Ok, thanks :)  Any suggestions about how to revise my code to produce the appropriate output?

Comment: What do you mean by _"using dynamic programming properly"_. Are you talking about [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) ?

Comment: I mean that I'm not caching the word-splits for the strings properly.  Sorry, I am not familiar with continuation, so that's probably not what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is due to your use of recursion in `splitintowords_version2`.

If the last character of the string cannot be found in the dictionary, it returns `''`. This, however, is then added to the previous results (`current_word + ' ' + splitintowords_version2(remaining_word)`). Therefore, in your example, the returned `''` is simply added to the already split `"cat in hat"` to produce `"cat in hat "`. Instead, you must check whether the return value of the recursion is empty and return an empty string if needed. **However**, this is not enough, because `splitintowords_version2` *also*  returns `''` for an empty input string. You can easily fix this by returning another value for an empty string or if the string could not be split (in the following example, I return `' '` instead of `''` for an empty string, because of which you may want to strip of whitespace using `string.strip` afterwards):

```
@memoize                
def splitintowords_version2(mystring):
    if len(mystring) < 1:
        return ' '
    else:
        for i in range(len(mystring)):
            current_word = mystring[:i+1]
            remaining_word = mystring[i+1:]
            if current_word in dictionary:
                remaining_split = splitintowords_version2(remaining_word)
                if len(remaining_split) > 0:
                    return current_word + ' ' + remaining_split
                else:
                    return '' # Last part was not in the dictionary.
            if i == len(mystring) - 1 and current_word not in dictionary:
                return ''
```

Another way might be to return `None` if the string could not be split and (if desired) wrapping that into another function that turns `None` in the *end result* (not inbetween calls) back into an empty string. To do this, replace `''` with `None` and the check `len(remaining_split) > 0` into `remaining_split != None`.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't work, because splitintowords_version2('catinhat') also returns ''.

Comment: Ah, true (just noticed). This is due to `splitintowords_version2` also returning `''` for an empty string (fixing that now...)